Text backdrop by ass formatting
I want to add box behind a word using ass subtitles formatting. The box should have border radius. the ass file later will be used by ffmpeg.
I have tried the BorderStyle=3 form stack ansers 1, 2 both of them do not provide a way to get rounded boxes. Also the BorderStyle=4 didn't work for me. In comments of last stack answer I found a possible reason that my libraries can be old, but anyway it doesn't seem that BorderStyle=4 will solve my problem of border radius. There is another way to achieve rounded box link to answer. I didn't figure it out how to install all the libs he explained there. Also the later answer seems to me over complicated. Is there an other way to make the borders of box rounded without suffering and pain? I also tried drawing the box with Drawing commands like
{\p1}m 0 0 s 100 0 100 100 0 100 c{\p0}

But it still doesn't seem to be the best way to achieve rounded borders.

I'll add some context. Basically speaking, the only way to achieve that in ASS is to use drawing commands in order to create rounded bounding box, pad it and then overlay text on top of that. Those libraries are meant to be use as a casual user, not a programmer, but there isn't any other obvious way to do that in ASS while accounting for width and height of text (there is not native way). If you like more code-approach, you can just use ILL module directly (Line.callBackExpand for converting text to shape, get it's path, then take min-max for bounding box, pad it and apply Path.RoundingPath).

All modules for Aegisub are written in Lua/MoonScript in this case it's MoonScript so you will need to grab some MoonScript compiler (and compile module to Lua for easier usage), easiest would be to just write script in Lua, but if you want to use some other language like Python then you would need some FFI for lua (for example lupa for Python). I might post some example later, but I don't have time for that now

And I really recommend just using ILL.Shapery for calculations because how text is rendered in ASS is really complicated, so taking measurements is not that easy (especially on Linux) you can just take a look at Libass renderer or VSFilter to see that it's not worth reinventing the whell.

I got stuck with ass approach because of invalid font sizes problem. Could you please give me any idea how to fix or to debug?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78936854/text-in-ass-subtitles-is-displayed-smaller-then-should

@YuukiKuna Thanks. Whenever you have time please combine your comments together add an example and I will accept it as an answer. Your answer would be more useful to others

I updated my answer here to use aegisub-cli (to fully automate it) and includes how to set it up both on Windows and Linux.

Eventually I made it with drawing commands.
The dialog looks something like this:
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:01.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\an7\p1\bord0\shad0\1a&HAA&\c&H000000&\pos(100,100)\an7}m 0 10 b 0 0 10 0 20 0 l 70 0 b 80 0 80 10 80 10 l 80 30 b 80 40 70 40 60 40 l 20 40 b 0 40 0 30 0 30 l 0 30{\p0}

The dialog consists of two parts; one is:
{\an7\p1\bord0\shad0\1a&HAA&\c&H000000&\pos(100,100)\an7}

which includes styling commands.
The second part is:
m 0 10 b 0 0 10 0 20 0 l 70 0 b 80 0 80 10 80 10 l 80 30 b 80 40 70 40 60 40 l 20 40 b 0 40 0 30 0 30 l 0 30

These are the coordinates to paint the rounded corner box. To dive deeper into drawing in ass file please check this doc - Drawing commands section. Also, to get the coordinates of a dynamic rounded rectangle, I used this code:
// Function to calculate points along a cubic Bezier curve
const calculateBezierPoints = (initialPoints, segments) => {
  const [P0, P1, P2, P3] = initialPoints
  const points = []
  for (let t = 0; t <= 1; t += 1 / segments) {
    const x = (1 - t) ** 3 * P0[0] + 3 * (1 - t) ** 2 * t * P1[0] + 3 * (1 - t) * t ** 2 * P2[0] + t ** 3 * P3[0]
    const y = (1 - t) ** 3 * P0[1] + 3 * (1 - t) ** 2 * t * P1[1] + 3 * (1 - t) * t ** 2 * P2[1] + t ** 3 * P3[1]
    points.push([x, y])
  }
  return points
}

// Function to generate a rounded rectangle
const generateRoundedRectangle = ({ width, height, radius, segments }) => {
  const coordinates = []

  // Top straight line (from top-left to top-right minus the radius)
  coordinates.push([radius, 0], [width - radius, 0])

  // Top-right corner
  const topRightInitialPoints = [[width - radius, 0], [width, 0], [width, radius], [width, radius]]
  const topRightCurve = calculateBezierPoints(topRightInitialPoints, segments)
  coordinates.push(...topRightCurve)

  // Right straight line (from top-right to bottom-right minus the radius)
  coordinates.push([width, radius], [width, height - radius])

  // Bottom-right corner
  const bottomRightInitialPoints = [[width, height - radius], [width, height], [width - radius, height], [width - radius, height]]
  const bottomRightCurve = calculateBezierPoints(bottomRightInitialPoints, segments)
  coordinates.push(...bottomRightCurve)

  // Bottom straight line (from bottom-right to bottom-left minus the radius)
  coordinates.push([width - radius, height], [radius, height])

  // Bottom-left corner
  const bottomLeftInitialPoints = [[radius, height], [0, height], [0, height - radius], [0, height - radius]]
  const bottomLeftCurve = calculateBezierPoints(bottomLeftInitialPoints, segments)
  coordinates.push(...bottomLeftCurve)

  // Left straight line (from bottom-left to top-left minus the radius)
  coordinates.push([0, height - radius], [0, radius])

  // Top-left corner
  const topLeftInitialPoints = [[0, radius], [0, 0], [radius, 0], [radius, 0]]
  const topLeftCurve = calculateBezierPoints(topLeftInitialPoints, segments)
  coordinates.push(...topLeftCurve)

  // Return the final coordinates for the rounded rectangle
  return coordinates
}

